# missing methode org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdirParent?

Tags: java, wildfly, apache-commons, java-ee-7

I'm using Wildfly 2019 with Java EE 7, while deploying application getting the following error. Searched on google didn't find any relevant answer.

1. Does it need by Wildfly internal issue?
2. Is it in my code and missing dependency?
3. Has to do with Wildfly version?

Anyone knows how to get rid of it?

**Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdirParent(Ljava/io/File;)V"}}**

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."parapik-web-1.0.95-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."parapik-web-1.0.95-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdirParent(Ljava/io/File;)V
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdirParent(Ljava/io/File;)V
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeUpdater.writePackageFile(NodeUpdater.java:298)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeUpdater.writeMainPackageFile(NodeUpdater.java:287)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskCreatePackageJson.execute(TaskCreatePackageJson.java:73)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:430)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:281)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.process(DevModeInitializer.java:182)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Which version of commons FileUtils are you using? forceMkdirParent appeared in 2.5 as far as I can see.

Comment: I don't have direct commons dependency on my project. i fixed it by adding commons dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding dependency as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 2023 and it is still valid fix. It helped me yesterday.